# Angular Unable to Resolve Dependency Tree

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just installed nodejs and angular while following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5E2AVpwsko and while creating my first project I got this error.

```
54 error code ERESOLVE
55 error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
56 error
57 error While resolving: hello-world2@0.0.0
57 error Found: @angular/core@15.1.3
57 error node_modules/@angular/core
57 error   @angular/core@"^15.1.0" from the root project
57 error
57 error Could not resolve dependency:
57 error peer @angular/core@"15.1.4" from @angular/animations@15.1.4
57 error node_modules/@angular/animations
57 error   @angular/animations@"^15.1.0" from the root project
57 error
57 error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
57 error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
57 error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
58 error
58 error
58 error For a full report see:
58 error C:\Users\vule2\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T18_19_54_573Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

Since I am new at this I haven't been able to find a fix on google.

Comment: just retry the npm command with `--legace-peer-deps`

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I managed to solve the problem with just a few npm commands, I linked them but a mod deleted it.

Comment: @NathanT. this shouldn't have to be the case with the latest versions of both npm and angular-cli. One would've thought that the Angular team is testing with the latest versions of node and npm.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I found the fix which I posted below but here are my versions:
Angular CLI: 15.1.4
Node: 18.14.0
NPM: 9.3.1

Comment: @Vukašin unfortunately, your fix below doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
npm cache verify  
npm cache clear --force 
npm install –g @angular/cli@latest
```